# Applet Does Not Display Image From URL in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, applet, appletviewer

An applet I made loads images from a URL. When I run this applet inside Eclipse using AppletViewer it displays the images. However when I run the applet in a browser after deploying it in Tomcat 7, the image does not display, only the grey background of the applet is displayed and no errors are printed to console.

I have also tried packing the image in the jar and loading it from there, but I get the same problem (works in Eclipse but not in Tomcat).

Is Tomcat the problem or is it something else?

Here is the complete code:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class LoadImage extends JApplet 
{   
Image image;

public LoadImage()
{
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Morus_bassanus_adu.jpg/50px-Morus_bassanus_adu.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(url);

        setSize(300, 300);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        add(label);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And if you do `new ImageIcon(url)` without ImageIO? (I know you want to resize.)

Comment: did you allow images to display?

Comment: Joop Eggen : This causes it to not display anything in Eclipse also.

Roman C : Do you mean in Tomcat? How do I do this?

Comment: With `label.setPreferredSize` and especially `label.setMinimumSize`?

Comment: Yes, I changed the code to 

`JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Morus_bassanus_adu.jpg/50px-Morus_bassanus_adu.jpg"));
   label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
   label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));`

And it has the effect that the image is not display in AppletViewer as well. I am convinced that the problem is not with the original code, but with Tomcat or a network or some Windows configuration.

Comment: Something for you to consider. Why should I, a potential end user, be prepared to accept digitally signed code just to see a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 URL url = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Morus_bassanus_adu.jpg/50px-Morus_bassanus_adu.jpg");

                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);        

                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,200));
                this.add(label);
```

Comment: This worked, thankyou! Can you please explain why BufferedImage works and not a normal Image? Is it because BufferedImage works over the internet and Image does not?